# Insert Sheet cell in URL for email body in Google APPs Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I've created a script that sends an email, part of the email body has a url to a google form in it.  I decided to try and prepopulate a section in the form with detail from a cell in a google sheet. The html email body contains:

```
<p style='color: #d32168; text-align: center;'>To access your completed chart, click <a href ='https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/LONGFORMID/viewform?entry.343368315="+ ProcessSheet.getRange(1, 3).getValues();"'>HERE</a> after 7 days</p>
```

When the script runs, it creates the url correctly, but for some reason it stops the rest of the HTML from adding after the url. I end up with the link not actually showing in the email and no further content showing after where I'd expected to see the url.

For example it look like

To access your completed chart, click

The link isn't there and nether is the content you'd expect to see after, however, in the execution log, I can see it's generated the Url correctly, so there must be an escape character I'm missing to ensure that the rest of the html is generated after the url.

What am I missing please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Put entire html within double quotes. As ProcessSheet.getRange(1, 3).getValues() is a variable, so you want to put it outside the double quotes, for it to evaluate before rendering.

```
"<p style='color: #d32168; text-align: center;'>
To access your completed chart, click 
<a href ='https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/LONGFORMID/viewform?entry.343368315="+ProcessSheet.getRange(1, 3).getValues()+"'>HERE</a> after 7 days</p>"
```

Comment: Thank you, your response nudged me in the correct direction.  I already had it all in double quotes, the thing that fixed it was removing the ; and adding the +.  I'd already tried adding + but hadn't removed the ;

Thanks again for your help!